# My application will no longer run

Tags: vb.net, security, visual-studio-2015

My application was running fine.  I went to lunch and just came back and now I keep getting this.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\WindowsApplication4.exe" to "bin\Debug\WindowsApplication4.exe". Access to the path 'obj\Debug\WindowsApplication4.exe' is denied.   WindowsApplication4
```

I rebooted, restarted VS, copied contents to another directory, installed the latest VS service pack.  Other applications continue to run, even ones that I had open at the same time this one was.  So its specific to this application.  Nothing changed between working and me coming back from lunch.

Any ideas?  I got way to much here to lose things.

Comment: Delete the file by hand.

Comment: Change the name of the executable via the project properties. Should solve the problem.

Comment: So the file wasn't even there.  I did a clean and rebuild and it was there, but said access is denied and couldn't not copy over to debug.  So I did it again, again it popped up with errors but actually started!  I closed it, ran again and the same errors continue without starting.

Comment: Yes changing he assembly name fixed it.  What in the world happen?

Comment: When I've experienced such it's usually been due to that my AntiVirus software has blocked it.

Comment: That's strange, especially in this corporate setting.  luckily I've not had this with any of my other programs here so fingers crossed.  But at least I know what to do.  Thanks Vincent.

Comment: make sure you have rights to location of your project